# Multiple has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In object model, I have

```
has_many :likes
has_many :hates
has_many :users, :through => :likes
has_many :users, :through => :hates
```

How do I get the list of users for likes? E.g. object.users <--- but how do I specify through likes or hates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give these two different associations different names. What about

```
has_many :likes
has_many :hates
has_many :likers, :through => :likes, :source => :user
has_many :haters, :through => :hates, :source => :user
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but the documentation of `has_many` (in ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods) says: "`:through` specifies an association through which to perform the query. [...] Options for `:class_name`, `:primary_key` and `:foreign_key` **are ignored**, as the association uses the source reflection." – so, the `:class_name` won't do anything, will it?

Comment: You're right, I updated the example to be compliant with the documentation, where it references the source association, from which it can be inferred that it's a User object.

Comment: I think the `:source => :user` should be `:source => :users`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I need to add source too. If not Rails will be looking for likers/liker in likes.

```
has_many :likes
has_many :hates
has_many :likers, :through => :likes, :class_name => 'User', :source => 'user'
has_many :haters, :through => :hates, :class_name => 'User', :source => 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
has_many :user_likes, :through => :likes, :class_name => 'User'
```