# More than one has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through, rails-models

So. I have users and movies. Users have watched some movies and not others. I want to express this relationship something like this:
[image: users and movies]

Note:

- Not sure if it matters; but movies don't *have* to be connected to a user; they can exist independently (i.e. Movie 1 has no relationship to User 2). Users can also exist independently; they don't have to have watched or unwatched movies (not pictured here, but you get the idea)
- One movie can be watched by one user but unwatched by another (grey vs. black connections)

My initial reaction is that this a `has_many :through` relationship, something like:

/models/user.rb:

```
def User
    has_many :movies, :through => :unwatched_movies
    has_many :movies, :through => :watched_movies
end
```

/models/movie.rb:

```
def Movie
    has_many :users, :through => :unwatched_movies
    has_many :users, :through => :watched_movies
end
```

But first of all, that code definitely doesn't work...

I want to be able to query for, say, `u.unwatched_movies` (where `u` is an instance of `User`, which doesn't seem to jive with the above.

I have a feeling this has something to do with `:source` or `:as`... but I'm feeling a little lost. Am I right in thinking that this is a 3-level hierarchy, where I need models for `User`, `UnwatchedMovieList`/`WatchedMovieList`, and `Movie`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528408/multiple-has-many-through) feels very close but I can't seem to make it work in this context.

Any help on how to write these models and migrations would be super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a relationship of omission - "unmatched movies". Which isn't a good idea, you should build up a history of movies watch (which is watched_movies) but then for unwatched you would want to find all movies minus watched movies. Then stick it in a function in User, like so:

```
def unwatched_movies
  Movie.where("id NOT IN ?", self.watched_movies.collect(&:movie_id))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I totally understand your point about a relationship of omission, but that's not exactly what I'm going for. I want a user to be able to have and curate an "unwatched movie" list. I don't always mean for "unwatched_movies" to simply mean "ALL movies from the entire movie catalog that I haven't watched", I mean "a list of movies I've specifically marked that I haven't watched". (Does that clarify at all?) Then, eventually, a user can mark one of their "unwatched movies" as "watched" (which would change its association).

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's actually a wish list. I've just noticed you're trying to call 'User.watched_movies' which won't work, you need an instance of a user first like so: '@user = User.first', '@user.unwatched_movies' search the difference between class and instance methods.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll edit that in the question. I am doing `u = User.first` and then `u.unwatched_movies` (I'm good on class/instance methods)

Comment: You could use `watched_movie_ids` instead of using collect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

Create these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_movies
    # Use a block to add extensions 
    has_many :movies, through: :user_movies, source: 'movie' do
        # this is an extension
        def watched
            where('user_movies.watched = ?', true)
        end
        def unwatched
            where('user_movies.watched = ?', false)
        end
    end
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_movies
    has_many :watchers, through: :user_movies, source: :user do
        # users who is an effective watcher 
        def watchers
            where('user_movies.watched = ?', true)
        end
        # users how marked it but did not watch it yet
        def markers
            where('user_movies.watched = ?', false)
        end
    end
end

class UserMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end

class CreateUserMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_movies do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :movie, index: true
      t.boolean :watched, default: false, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :user_movies, :users
    add_foreign_key :user_movies, :movies
  end
end
```

then for queries

```
@user = User.first
@user.movies.watched
@user.movies.unwatched

@movie = Movie.first
@movie.watchers.watchers
@movie.watchers.markers
```

Answer (score 0):

The following set of associations should cover your use case of being able to explicitly mark movies watched and unwatched. It makes use of a join table called `user_movies` that simply contains the following fields: `user_id, movie_id, and watched`

```
class User
  has_many :unwatched_user_movies, -> { where(watched: false) }, class_name: 'UserMovie'
  has_many :unwatched_movies, through: :unwatched_user_movies, class_name: 'Movie'

  has_many :watched_user_movies, -> { where(watched: true) }, class_name: 'UserMovie'
  has_many :watched_movies, through: :watched_user_movies, class_name: 'Movie'
end

class UserMovie
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end

class Movie
  has_many :user_movies
end
```